# Proving properties about complex exponential

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

I defined $a^z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ as

$a^z = \exp(z\log(a))$

and I proved it is continous, now I want to show that

$a^n = a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot \ldots \cdot a$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

so since $n$ is just a real number here I thought this wouldnt be to bad, but I'm stuck.

$a^n = \large\exp(n\log(a)) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n\log(a))^k}{k!} = \frac{n^k*\log(a)^k}{k!} = \frac{k(n^k)\log(a)}{k!}$

I don't know where to go from here though.

Comment: So $2^3=3\cdot 3\cdot 3?$ After you realise your mistake, I suggest you prove it by induction.

Comment: Note that $a^n=a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot \ldots\cdot a$.

Comment: @GitGud haha, thank you for pointing that out!!!

Comment: Your sum is OK, but what comes after it is quite dodgy.

Comment: @vonbrand what do you mean? also do you guys know how I can make the text bigger in latex? I feel like it is hard for you to read as it is now.

Comment: From the third equals on is just wrong.

Comment: do you mean because I left out the sigma? that was just laziness? :(

Comment: @terribleatmath You can use commands like `\large, \huge` or simply enclose all the math in double \$, instead of single \$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
a^n &=& \exp(n\log(a)), \\
    &=& \exp(\log(a) + \ldots + \log(a)), \quad \mbox{n times}\\
    &=& \exp(\log(a))\exp(\log(a))\ldots \exp(\log(a)) \\
    &=& a a \ldots a. 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: beautiful, don't even need the series- Thank you!!